# Does World of Warcraft Cataclysm Collector's Edition have a separate key for the exclusive in-game pet?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The title says it all. However, I will explain. Are there two keys in the Cataclysm Collector's Edition box? One key to upgrade the account to play Cataclysm content. Another key that is used to retrieve the exclusive in-game pet only available with the purchase of the Collector's Edition?

Comment: _Please include reference link if possible (but not required). Such as a blue post._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in all the other collector's editions, nope. The account serial is tied to the pet and vise-versa. I don't see why they would change this policy, since every other item in the collector's edition is exactly the same as previous versions just updated. Ex. Art book, dvd, music. So basically if you want the pet you gotta pay for the collectors edition new.

Comment: Would vote your answer up. However, I don't have the rep to do so yet. Thank you again.

Comment: no prob, just happy to help.